# Run gitlab server with bundle: command not found error

Tags: gitlab

I have no idea what happened

sudo service gitlab start

```
Starting both the GitLab Unicorn and Sidekiqscript/web: line 21: bundle: command not found
......
```

Check my system information

```
System information
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  yes
RVM Version:    1.25.19
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p545
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.5.3
Rake Version:   10.1.1

GitLab information
Version:    6.6.4
Revision:   42e34ae
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: postgresql
URL:        http://localhost:1680
HTTP Clone URL: http://localhost:1680/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@localhost:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.8.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: A couple of workaround have been published since in issue 6019. See my [edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22217289/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently followed in [issue 6019](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6019), and has no definitive resolution yet.

It also occurs on a reboot, where the server hangs with an increasing number of dots after:

```
Shutting down both Unicorn and Sidekiq........
```

On startup, you can see:

```
Removing stale Sidekiq web server pid. This is most likely caused by the Sidekiq crashing the last time it ran.
```

---

The issue 6019 includes now [this comment](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6019#issuecomment-40658748):

```
rvmsudo -u git bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

> I've solved this issue after read [this guide](http://blog.compunet.co.za/gitlab-installation-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/).
> Gitlab service is executed as you expect...

Still not enough though, with a GitLab 6.7.2

---

That issue now includes the message from Terry Wang:

> I had exactly the same problem after upgrading to 6.8.x. Later on I figure out that it was the init script.
>
> Ruby is installed via `rbenv` + `ruby-build`, looks like the gitlab init script is NOT able to
>
> Workaround

1. add `$HOME/.rbenv/shims` to PATH in the gitlab init script
2. OR simply create a symbolic link for bundle in `/usr/local/bin` (or whatever appropriate) like below without changing anything

   su - git
   ln -s $(which bundle) /usr/local/bin

> Hope `rbenv` support will be added soon.

---

Alexander Adam added back in May:

> I have the same problem.
> But in my case I used a local `rbenv-installation` for the gitlab user so I had to add `PATH=/home/$app_user/.rbenv/bin:/home/$app_user/.rbenv/shims:$PATH` so that the init-script will use the `rbenv-bins`.