# sudo: bundle: command not found when upgrading GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/blob/master/doc/update/8.7-ce-to-ee.md to upgrade our GitLab CE server to GitLab EE

Server is CentOS 6.7, with GitLab CE originally installed by

```
$ curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
$ sudo yum install gitlab-ce
```

And the current version is

```
$ rpm -q gitlab-ce
gitlab-ce-8.7.5-ce.0.el6.x86_64
```

I follow the steps from [the upgrade guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/blob/master/doc/update/8.7-ce-to-ee.md) linked above, but get an error

```
$ cd /home/git/gitlab
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

I am aware of this problem from earlier work and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456998/why-is-sudo-bundle-command-not-found) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647745/using-sudo-bundle-exec-raises-bundle-command-not-found-error) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213822/run-gitlab-server-with-bundle-command-not-found-error). I think the base cause is that we have installed from rpm, so [should use "gitlab-rake" instead of "bundle exec rake"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/maintenance/README.md#invoking-rake-tasks).

That will suffice for the above problem, but the next steps in [the guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/blob/master/doc/update/8.7-ce-to-ee.md) include

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install ...
```

It seems that `gitlab-rake` will not work for that, so I need to actually use the `bundle` command. But I have no idea which one - there are currently 19 different files on disk called `.../bin/bundle`, of which 7 came from the gitlab rpm.

So: which "bundle" command should I use when the guide tells me to

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install ....
```

?

Comment: try `which bundle` as normal user and use absolute path to that one with `sudo -u git`

Comment: If what @mb21 said doesn't work, you can also try installing bundle manually.  If I recall correctly, `sudo -H gem install -g bundle` should work.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help your specific case but I've been facing a similar issue with GitLab CE (Community Edition) running on CentOS 7.  Everything was working smoothly but when trying to run some of the documented service commands that make use of `bundle`, I found out that `bundle` wasn't in anyone's `$PATH`: neither root's nor the `git` user's.

In the end, systemd pointed me to the right environment, namely:

```
# systemctl status gitlab-runsvdir.service | grep Loaded
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gitlab-runsvdir.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
# grep '^Exec' /usr/lib/systemd/system/gitlab-runsvdir.service
ExecStart=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
# grep PATH /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
PATH=/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Et voilà.

That script (`/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start`) also includes a fair bit of scaffolding to set the correct runtime environment, which is useful to study and apply where appropriate.

YMMV obviously, particularly if you're not running GitLab under systemd but a similar approach might work with other init systems.

Finally it's worth noting that (as pointed out in the original q), any `rake` command should be run using `gitlab-rake`.